# HTML Select, embed object with text?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to have a HTML Select containing elements, not just text values but say an object (specifically i'd like to add a JQuery slider with the text) but if someone could advice me generally how to do this, i could investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, definitely not. The default `select` element is rendered by the browser and can not be extended beyond its standard behaviour.

You would need to look into entirely JavaScript-powered SELECT alternatives.

[Here's](http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements#9) a small list of jQuery based SELECT alternatives; there are many, many more.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, don't use an HTML select element. Use a div or whatever, and implement the whole thing in javascript. Then you can add whatever functionality you like.